# 'apt upgrade' was interrupted, I did 'apt autoremove' afterwards. System completely ripped out

Tags: debian, apt

My system has been experiencing some port 80 & 443 attacks which resulted in heavy network connection instability. Regardless I did `apt upgrade` followed by `apt update` to go from Debian 11.0 to 11.1 but the downloading got interrupted. Regardless I commenced `apt upgrade` again and it seemed everything went fine, initially. But apparently `apt autoremove` detected basically every package and deleted everything, bricked my system. The `sudo` command isn't even working.

Is it because of my system was hacked? Why would seemingly well-carried out `apt upgrade` (despite the interrupted first attempt) cause `apt autoremove` to remove everything? How should I prevent such trouble when the same thing happens?

Answer (score 1):

> But apparently apt autoremove detected basically every package and
> deleted everything, bricked my system. The sudo command isn't even
> working.

apt autoremove would never remove a package unless your system and all its applications and services don't need it anymore.

However, in a situation like an interruption of the upgrade process, I prefer to `check` and list all broken packages, `configure` the packages that only unpacked, then fix all packages/depedencies with `-f install`. So my sequence of actions would be as follows:

- `apt-get check`: This command is a diagnostic tool. It does an update of the package lists and checks for broken dependencies.
- `dpkg --configure -a`: this will configure all unpacked but unconfigured packages.
- `apt -f install`: This will fix all broken installation, errors like *unmet dependencies*.
- `apt-get autoremove`: to remove any unneeded dependencies that have been pulled in by other packages.
- `apt update && apt upgrade` to re-update/upgrade the packages.

*you may need to run `su -` to run these commands from root since you have `sudo` broken!*

Also, I would suggest to keep watching `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` while doing all the commands above to see and observe all things that are happening during the process.